# How to preserv the state of a dynamically created ListBox ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, listbox

I want a ListBox(multi-selectable) in my form which is generated dynamically from a file and after the submit I want the same fields still being selected.

this is how I do it now:

```
<select name="select" size="20" multiple style="Width: 100%">
  <% Response.WriteFile(@"~\Catalogs\"+usergroup+".htm"); %>
</select>
```

But this way the selection is gone after the submit.

Does anyone has a better solution for my problem.
(the file does not necessarily have to be the final HTML-file I just want to be able to alter the value + text of the ListBox from the file)

Great thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically generate items in the code behind and add them to your list. To do so, you need to add the `runat="server"` attribute to your `select`, or use the `asp:DropDownList` server control.

It looks like you are inserting the contents of a file verbatim into the list. You will probably need to change that into more structured data, or at least read it as structured data.

Example:

```
<%-- in markup of control/page --%>
<asp:DropDownList  runat="server" id="ddlCatalogs" />

// in codebehind

// to make this work, you'll need to read the file one line/item as a time
foreach( var item in listOfItemsInFile ){
    var li = new ListItem();

    // TODO: populate "li" from the item's data

    // add it to the server control's collection...now it's a part of the ASP.Net
    // page lifecycle
    this.ddlCatalogs.Controls.Add( option );
}
```

Once you are treating the dropdown as a server control, you can maintain state in a variety of ways (by default ViewState will take care of it, but with many items in the list ViewState will become quite large).

Alternatively, you could go in a different direction (no server controls involved) and just look at the raw `Request.Form` collection to see if it contains data for your select list, and write that back into your page.

Even in this scenario, it would probably be necessary to enumerate the input file in a more structured fashion so that you can select the correct option.

Comment: Thank you! I now use the <asp: ListBox> and generate the Text and Values in the code behind. Just didn't know how to start here..